# express-session entry not completely removed from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express-session

I am using [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) along with [connect-mongodb-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongodb-session) packages in a `nodeJS` app to store sessions in mongodb database.

**Problem**

When I try to delete a session saved in the database using `req.session.destroy()` function, it removes user-related information from the session entry saved in a database but it doesn't remove the session entry completely from the database.

**Question**

How can i fix this problem? Why is session entry completely removed from the database?

**Code**

```
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const MongoDbStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(expressSession);

const sessionStore = new MongoDbStore({
    uri: dbConnectionStr,
    collection: 'sessions'
});

app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'sessionsecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore
}));
```

code where `req.session.destroy` is called

```
const logout = (req, res) => {
    try {

         // destroy session saved in db
            req.session.destroy((error) => {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error('something went wrong while logging out')
            }
            res.redirect('/login');
        });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(utils.standardResponse('error', error.message));
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you using passport?

Comment: no, i am not using passport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who might encounter this problem, here's the solution

when setting up `express-session`, set the `unset` option to `destroy`

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    unset: 'destroy'                   <-------- 
}));
```

then in your route handler whenever you want to destroy the session entry in session store, just set `req.session` to `null`

```
const logout = (req, res) => {
    req.session = null;   
    res.redirect('/login');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    // req.session.isAuth = true;
    res.render("./login");
});
```

by removing req.session.isAuth = true from login route,
When you log out,  the session will be removed from the database completely if you're using this statement in login route.

For me the same problem is occuring frequently. So I used this trick.